# Serialize webservice calls and callbacks

Tags: ios, web-services, serial-processing

I have a class that sends webservice calls and delivers the response via delegation.
I now want to add a caching layer in between the views and my webservice class.
This new class should serialize the calls in a way that every call is delayed until the callback of the previous call has finished.

I tried to realize that with GCD:

```
- (void)callWebserviceFunctionX {
    dispatch_group_notify(self.serviceGroup, self.serialQueue, ^{
        dispatch_group_enter(self.serviceGroup);

        // call webservice
    });
}
```

And in the callback:

```
-(void)callbackFunctionXWithResponse:(id)response {
    // do something

    dispatch_group_leave(self.serviceGroup);
}
```

The idea to group each call and its callback with `dispatch_group_enter`and `dispatch_group_leave` and wait for previous groups using `dispatch_group_notify`.

However, this approach does not seem to work as I intended.
Is there a better way to achieve this?

**UPDATE:**
I tried every combination of `dispatch_group_enter`, `dispatch_group_leave`, `dispatch_group_notify`and `dispatch_group_async` I can think of without success.
I also thought about `NSOperation`and `NSOperationQueue`, but - if I understood correctly - that would force me to write a separate class for every webservice call.

Is there another alternative I did not think of yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd be better off using NSOperation, dependencies between them to ensure serialisation and NSOperationQueue to run them.

To avoid creating a NSOperation subclass for each request you could use the builtin NSBlockOperation, you provide a block to each instance and adding dependencies between the NSBlockOperation instances should give you the aimed serialisation.

Hope this helps.

Regards

Comment: Thanks!I chose this answer over the first one because it does not include a third party framework and avoids a ton of subclasses by using `NSBlockOperation`.

Comment: I'm using a solution like this successfully. I've also added 

operationQueue.isSuspended = true 

at the start of each block and 

operationQueue.isSuspended = false

in the completionBlock of the asynchronous web service that runs in each block.
Also with operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1

This allows my queue to be serialized and also to stop processing when encountering an error so that appropriate recovery can take place.

Answer (score 2):

You could use MKNetworkKit as your Networking solution. This uses NSOperationQueue under the hood and you can use NSOperation dependencies to serialize your request / responses. MKNetworkKit also supports caching of the responses so might help with your caching implementation also.

MKNetworkKit Overview
http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/products/ios-framework-introducing-mknetworkkit/

Someone had a similar problem using MKNetworkKit and GCD
[MKNetworkKit and GCD dispatch_group_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858527/mknetworkkit-and-gcd-dispatch-group-t)